# Child Relationships in SOQL Queries Aren't Working

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, childrelationship

So I have these 3 queries, and all of them throw an error about the relationship not being recognized.

```
this.lineItems = [SELECT QuoteLineItems.Product2Id FROM Quote WHERE Id = :activeQuote.Id];
[SELECT Products__r.Id FROM Product_Hierarchy__c LIMIT 1];
[SELECT Hierarchy_Parent__r.Id FROM Product_Hierarchy__c LIMIT 1];
```

Technically, I only need the first line in my code, but I put the other two lines for my own testing purposes for this error.

These lines give the following errors and won't allow me to save to the server:

```
Save error: SELECT Hierarchy_Parent__r.Id FROM Product_Hierarchy__c

ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Didn't understand relationship 'Hierarchy_Parent__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Save error: SELECT Products__r.Id FROM Product_Hierarchy__c

ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Didn't understand relationship 'Products__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Save error: SELECT QuoteLineItems.Product2Id FROM Quote

ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Didn't understand relationship 'QuoteLineItems' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

These are the relevant relationships in the schema:

[image: The child relationships for Product_Hierarchy__c]

[image: The child relationship for Quote]

Something seems wrong, and I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child relationships always use a sub-select:

```
this.quoteRecord = [SELECT (SELECT Product2Id FROM QuoteLineItems) FROM Quote WHERE Id = :activeQuote.Id];
```

If you want to query the children directly, use the child object:

```
this.lineItems = [SELECT Product2Id FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId = :activeQuote.Id];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to query the child records of Parent, for that you need to use sub-query

```
Select Id,(Select Id from QuoteLineItems) from Quote
```

Like this you need to do other query.

Comment: This answer is basically a duplicate of the existing.